# Is there a way to use Selenium to automate testing in Safari 11 without the 'glass pane'

Tags: javascript, selenium, safari, automated-tests

According to the WebKit [documentation for Safari 10](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/,%20documentation)

"When running a WebDriver test in Safari, test execution is confined to special Automation windows that are isolated from normal browsing windows, user settings, and preferences. Automation windows are easy to recognize by their orange Smart Search field."

In that version  of the browser I was able to run automation for Safari without the 'glass pane' by doing:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    safari = require('selenium-webdriver/safari');
    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('safari')
    .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
    .build();
```

I believe that the reason this worked was because starting the webdriver and using the selenium standalone server hub and SafariDriver extension allowed this for remote automation as part of Selenium Grid. It no longer seems to work in Safari 11.

The statement in the documentation "The automaticInspection capability will preload the Web Inspector and JavaScript debugger in the background; to pause test execution and bring up Web Inspector’s Debugger tab, you can simply evaluate a debugger; statement in the test page." would be useful but I take that to mean that I need to add debugging statements to the source code, which is not something QA is empowered to do in my situation.

Is there a way to use Selenium to automate testing in Safari 11 without the 'glass pane' AT ALL? Any reading I might need to do is welcomed; there are far too many problems that I am encountering when running in glass pane to make fixing each of those an efficient way forward.

Comment: I'm intensely curious... what's the big rub with "the glass pane"?  What kind of pain is this causing?

Comment: There are a few HTML elements that can be clicked for other browsers (in particular <select><option>) that are not clickable by Safari. There is also an explicit wait that happens at the very end of my test script that is a file save dialog, which cannot be reliably timed since it varies dependant upon the amount of data being saved, and some server-side things over which I have no control. In some cases this dialog is not detected, even though it has displayed. Since it is a long running test, the option to dismiss the dialog manually when needed saves me from having to re-execute the test.

Comment: @QualiT, have you found a solution for disabling this "glass pane" in Safari? I'm also stuck with some popups interactions and Sikuli clicks and looking for a way to disable glass pane.

Comment: @sunigos No, I have gone over to using the Glass Pane. There are plusses and minuses, but there are some really annoying workarounds that I now need to do to make my scripts work for Safari, and there is one script that I still cannot get to complete. Good luck!

Comment: Update: I eventually figured out how to do all of the things I need to do in Glass Pane. The upside is that Safari does not interrupt my work with popups, or by grabbing focus. The downside is that because I cannot interact with the browser while the script is running, I occasionally have to spend more time figuring out what precisely is happening when a given selector does not work. Nominal tradeoff, I guess.

Comment: @QualiT Do you perhaps know how to disable it now? Safari version 13. I have an issue where I am not able to interact with authentication popup using Selenium and I wanted to interact with it using AWT Robot but the glass pane doesn't allow that. I just want to click cancel on the auth popup.

Comment: No, but thanks for reminding me that I could use glass pane. It's been so long since I used it that i had forgotten how it works.